# Statistical estimation algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math

I'm not sure if this question is appropriate for Stack Overflow but I'll give it a try anyway.
I have some data as follows:

[image]

I also have another set of data that I believe follows a similar distribution but I only know the total percent (e.g. 30% rather than 17%.) Can anyone suggest an algorithm to estimate the %s for each individual tier based on the new total % and the original distribution?

Comment: This is a good questionfor SO. I'd edit your test though and remove your first sentance. The first couple of sentances of a question are shown as tooltips or previews, so you should forgo the formalities and get right to the meat.

Comment: Should the possible total remain fixed?

Comment: It's really not clear to me what you are trying to do. I'll try and answer your question if you can explain in detail what all of your measurements mean, how many of them you have, and what exactly you want to estimate.

Comment: I'll argue that this is not a SO problem. Really it has nothing to do with programming. A better place to ask this question is perhaps a newsgroup like sci.stat, or sci.stat.math. Regardless, were I to try to answer the question, I would need a much clearer explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You question is unclear.  If you want to estimate a new total percent by including the additinal data you are getting you must have quantity associated with your percentage so that you can create a meaninful weighted average.

If you want to determine if the new set of data has a different distribution than the historical data there are several tests mostly doing obtuse calculations on cummulative actual vs. expected percentages of values falling underneath a particular value.  There is a lot of literature on the subject on comparing the distributions of two populations.

For paired samples [Wilcoxon-Rank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) is a standard method if you can make no assumptions about the distribuion of the data.  For non paired data [non-parametric statistics](http://books.google.com/books?id=1Nrzy56BGPwC&pg=PA114&lpg=PA114&dq=distribution+free+rank+test&source=bl&ots=tRstainvDm&sig=Yv4hcjTkOBqCwEio0zvYxQl4M84&hl=en&ei=0wD1SbKwCJe-M8a6gLkP&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1#PPA55,M1) exist but they require some in depth study.

Answer (score 1):

**Step-1:** If your overall percentage 17% → 30% then, Actual (total) 105 → ~189.

**Step-2:** This number needs to be distributed over all elements in **Actual column**

From here things become non-linear, and we need some formula for arriving at Actual from POssible. And this needs to be a function of total.

i.e., function (possible, total (actual)) = actual.

If we can arrive at the above, then it might work ;)

Comment: huh?  I guess I am not getting somthing fundamental.

Answer (score 0):

If your new total is x, then put (22/627)*x as possible for tier 1, and (21/627)*x as actual for tier 1, which will give you the same percentage as before for tier 1.  Then do the same thing for the other tiers (so possible for tier 2 is (45/627)*x, etc.).